# How to make 'navigation.push()' works for integration test in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, cross-platform

It is my first time using an integration test in Flutter.

I write the test code below :

```
testWidgets('Navigate to password page', (tester) async {

      // ! Launch the app.
      app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

      // ! Tap on the enter user login page
      await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('enter_login_page_btn')));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      // Check if the new page is displayed correctly
      expect(find.byKey(const Key('page_user_login')), findsWidgets);

      // Enter text into the login/email input field.
      await tester.enterText(
          find.byKey(const Key('user_input_login')), "test@test.com");
      await tester.testTextInput.receiveAction(TextInputAction.done);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

      // ! Tap on the validate user login button.
      await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('validate_login_btn')));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
}
```

this is code when the 'login' button is pressed :

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => PasswordPage(
                  email ?? '',
                  key: const Key('page_user_password'), 
                ),
                maintainState: true,
              ),
            );
```

In normal manual test, the navigation works perfectly, but when I try to test it using the integration test, nothing happen, it doesn't navigate to the next page which is the password page and the test ends.

Does any one has any idea why the navigation is not working in integration test ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check Widget Tree: Ensure widgets are present and accessible using find.byType or find.byKey.
2. Ensure Proper Widget Keys: Confirm keys are unique and correctly assigned.
   Wait for Navigation: Use tester.pumpAndSettle() to wait for navigation completion.
3. Check Navigator Stack: Verify the navigation stack is updated correctly.
   Handle Asynchronous Operations: Properly handle asynchronous tasks with await.
   Debugging: Use print statements or breakpoints to debug navigation.
   Mock Dependencies: Consider mocking external dependencies for consistent behavior.